SVG Sprite still working even after removing object
In my index.shtml I have
<object data="icons/svg-sprite.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="0" height="0" style="display: none;"></object>

In my svg-sprite.svg I have
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" focusable="false">
<defs>
        <symbol id="html_element_group_core" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" focusable="false" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M12,0C5.369,0,0,5.369,0,12s5.369,12,12,12s12-5.369,12-12S18.631,0,12,0zM12,21.6c-5.298,0-9.6-4.302-9.6-9.6S6.702,2.4,12,2.4s9.6,4.302,9.6,9.6S17.298,21.6,12,21.6zM12,7.2c-2.654,0-4.8,2.146-4.8,4.8s2.146,4.8,4.8,4.8s4.8-2.146,4.8-4.8S14.654,7.2,12,7.2z" />
    </symbol>
    </defs>

Again in my index.shtml I have
    <svg class="group_icon svg_icon">
        <use xlink:href="icons/svg-sprite.svg#html_element_group_core"></use>
    </svg>

Notice the use is using icons/svg-sprite.svg#html_element_group_core directly refreing the svg-sprite.svg file.
The issue is even if I remove object it still works. Why? If so why do I need the object at all? Is it because of icons/svg-sprite.svg#html_element_group_core

Who told you that you needed to add the object element? Sounds like an advice taken out of context.

I am sure I read somewhere to use the object element so that its loaded once and can be used multiple times

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54736212/trying-to-use-svg-sprites

@chrwahl: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476526/do-i-use-img-object-or-embed-for-svg-files?rq=1

@Jawad: <object> used to be one of the best methods when svg support was still inconsistent ... when internet explorer was still a thing. Nowadays all browsers support svg and external use references. However you may still encounter issues with external use refs especially when it comes to referenced svg elements/features like clip-paths, masks, gradients or even styles when defined in a <symbol>

You are mixing 2 different methods
xlink:href="icons/svg-sprite.svg#html_element_group_core" is a URI,
thus loads the external SVG file and only displays the Symbol.
Note: href is enough xlink: is oldskool notation.

would that mean the svg-sprite.svg is loaded every time causing an extra http request when using multiple use

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54736212/trying-to-use-svg-sprites

yes, loaded again, but from the cache; the # does not make it a unique URI
